# What's the function of the Alt Gr key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I read somewhere that the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key found on some layouts is a substitute for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

However, what can this combination be used for? Are there any documented shortcuts using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Delete

Answer (score 31, accepted):

IBM named this key "alternate graphic" and it's not a substitute for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd>, though <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> was implemented as a substitute for <kbd>ALT GR</kbd> in Windows. It is a key modifier (like CTRL or SHIFT) that enables a different input than is normally expected of a key.

Depending on your keyboard and location setup, it can be used to produce characters with diacritical marks when used in conjunction with alphabetic keys (most often vowels), and the third symbol that is printed on some keys, for example, € (<kbd>ALT GR</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>) or ¦ (<kbd>ALT GR</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>) that appear on my UK keyboard. Continental European keyboards generally have many more keys with extra symbols printed on them which correspond letters with the various types of diacritical marks used in those languages.

See *[AltGr key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)* for more information.

Comment: I always thought it stood for Alt Green, as I remember the key was printed with green letters on the IBM PC/AT keyboard, but just saying `Alt`.  It's strange that the Wikipedia article does not even mention that.

Comment: I, for a long time, thought it meant "Alt German"...

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard: I thought the same too.

Comment: Nice pointing out that `Alt Gr` is implemented as `Ctrl`+`Alt` but `Ctrl`+`Alt` does not map to `Alt Gr`.

Comment: In India, in some designated keyboards, the key Alt Gr + 4 gives the Indian currency symbol (₹)

Answer (score 9):

For some keyboards, it allows some alternate combinations. In some keyboards it allows the cent symbol or the euro symbol - Wikipedia has [a pretty comprehensive list of combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) using Alt Gr.

However using a US/Windows keymap, it doesn't do anything in most cases.

Comment: Even some US layouts have a <€> somewhere on them (on <5> in my case).

Comment: mine is a british keyboard set to american ;p. it has the euro symbol on the 4 if it were on british keysets

Answer (score 4):

Also, handy for people with accessibility needs who have to do a Ctrl+alt+del. You try it one-handed.

Comment: I doubt that works?

Comment: @Arjan It doesn't work.

Comment: Does on every keyboard I've used. Maybe it's a UK-keymap thing.

Comment: @Bonus Never worked for me on any keyboard I used, even on UK keymap. Maybe there's some not so obvious setting that controls that?

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the [secure attention key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure%5Fattention%5Fkey) if this was enabled without any specific setting, like @Andreja wonders about?

Comment: @Arjan Maybe some keyboards produce different scancode for AltGr? Could it be that of some keyboards AltGr is actually configured to behave as ctrl+alt?

Comment: The C+A+D sequence is handled at a much lower level than the `AltGr` to `Ctrl`+`Alt` conversion (at least on Windows and Linux), so they are not going to work exactly the same. (Except perhaps in the case of a keyboard sending `Ctrl`+`Alt` scancodes.)

Answer (score 4):

Alt gr is necessary for some languages like Polish:

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> = ą

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> = ś

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> = Ń

Comment: Such keyboard layout can lead to interesting bugs and issues. Read *[The curious case of the disappearing Polish S](https://medium.engineering/the-curious-case-of-disappearing-polish-s-fa398313d4df)*.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is implemented like this.

You can test the vkCode from the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT to see what you get.

Mapped enum list from [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/VirtualKeys.html), [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/HookType.html), and www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html

It should be equivalent to this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

`isAltGr ? (Keys) (1 << 19) : Keys.None`

```
private static Keys BuildKeyData(Keys virtualKeyCode) => virtualKeyCode | (IsDownControl ? Keys.Control : Keys.None) | (IsDownShift ? Keys.Shift : Keys.None) | (IsDownAlt ? Keys.Alt : Keys.None) | (IsAltGr ? (Keys) (1 << 19) : Keys.None);
private static bool IsDownControl => IsKeyPressed((ushort)VirtualKeys.LeftControl) || IsKeyPressed((ushort)VirtualKeys.RightControl);
private static bool IsDownShift => IsKeyPressed((ushort)VirtualKeys.LeftShift) || IsKeyPressed((ushort)VirtualKeys.RightShift);
private static bool IsDownAlt => IsKeyPressed((ushort)VirtualKeys.LeftMenu) || IsKeyPressed((ushort)VirtualKeys.RightMenu) || IsKeyPressed((ushort)VirtualKeys.Menu);
private static bool IsAltGr => IsDownControl && IsDownAlt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Important Alt+Gr key combinations on a default German keyboard are:

- @ ... AltGr + Q (if you press the same keys on a OS X keyboard, the application will be closed)
- € ... AltGr + E
- { ... AltGr + 7
- [ ... AltGr + 8
- ] ... AltGr + 9
- } ... AltGr + 0
- \ ... AltGr + ß
- ~ ... AltGr + +
- | ... AltGr + <
- µ ... AltGr + M