# The number keys in the top row all have a number a punctuation and an accent mark or other mark

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using a my Dell Inspiron 15 model 3000 laptop running Windows 8.1 and when I want to type question mark it types an accent mark (the third thing on the key) I can’t get it to change to question mark. All the numbers on this line have a third character, some type the second and some type the third mark.

I use ENG. Great Britain Language, I have tried the ENG Canadian, US. etc. same results.

This has touch screen keyboard and these work properly, it does show the touch screen keyboard as a different layout.

Comment: Is NumLock on? Have you tried turning it off? 
Can you link to a photo of the keyboard you have? I've looked around on the web and can't find any that match your description.

Comment: How do I link to a photo.... sorry just don't have that knowledge,

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've changed the input method, and not just the language?

`Control Panel > Clock, Language and Region > Change input methods`

For the language you want to use, press the options button, next to it. Then modify the input methods to your liking there. The most common one is `US` or `United States-Iternational`

I've made the mistake before by changing just the language. It sounds like that's what happened with you too.

**EDIT:**
It seems that the keyboard layout your laptop was shipped with is `Canadian French`. If you would follow the steps described above for this layout, then the input method would be correctly configured.

Comment: Ive tried to do what you asked and it is the same result, This is an odd Keyboard, purchased ar Best Buy, it has extra keys for French and all of the top line number keys have a third possible mark, Ive tried the AltGR key hoping that might help but it seems to not work at all .

Comment: Does the keyset change at all when you applied a different input method? For expample, pressing `@` would result in an `@` on one setting, but different with the other setting.

Comment: NO, its the same no matter which I use

Comment: That is really weird, just to confirm, you have multiple input methods here? [screenshot](http://puu.sh/gcDKs/676f2f17f0.png) And can you switch between them using Windows-key + Space?

Comment: Yes I have multiple input and the windows shifr combo works

Comment: If you can tell me how to link a photo I took a picture of this keyboard

Comment: Upload it to a service like imgur.com and link it here.

Comment: <a href="http://imgur.com/HV7srVY"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/HV7srVY.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>

Comment: I just posted the imgur linkfor you, and thanks for your help...

Comment: Check the answer, I've found the correct layout for you.

Comment: I have just done as you said and it works, ? ?   LMAO, now the quotation mark shows up as È ..

Comment: Well, this is the correct layout for you physical keyboard as far as I know. Good luck anyways!

Comment: THank you very much, I now have a laptop that is almost 100 %, John

Comment: it is common, with such layouts, to access the "3rd" character using the right-hand side "Alt" key - "Alt Gr" on your keyboard. See this question for more info: http://superuser.com/questions/220071/whats-the-function-of-the-alt-gr-key